# Accessing an Rmd/Shiny script remotely

Tags: r, shiny

I wrote a script that uses R markdown and shiny. It works fine locally, and when in R studio, it lets me open it in a browser where it also works fine.

http://127.0.0.1:5302/source.Rmd is the URL on my computer that it's at.

Is it possible to have that accessible from another computer?

Like an alternative to just using shiny and doing something like:

```
library(shiny)
runApp("RunMe",host="0.0.0.0",port=3168)
```

Edit /Error: 
Warning message:
In readLines(file) :
  incomplete final line found on '/private/var/folders/tp/pml977354gs9nf8nhsdnp6440000gn/T/RtmpefzZj1/filed9f719c508e/temp.Rmd'

Comment: you can publish on shinyapps.io

Comment: Is there no way I can do it without having to do the whole script in Shiny? I can't keep the markdown structure?

Comment: There is also rpubs.com

Comment: Ok thank you. so in Rstudio I set up rsconnect and published to rstudio so its now shown as a running application. However ,when I go to the URL it says 'Not found'. Studio reports successfully deployed but gives error ive added to OP

Comment: The error looks to be a a syntax issue with the Rmd document.It's difficult to diagnose your issue. You say your "published to rstudio" (which is not possible) and you have not provided the Rmd code.